# How can i check if teletext is available in the stream?

Tags: java, vlcj

I use the vlcj to get Teletext in my mediaplayer. It works great!

```
PlayerGUI.player.setTeletextPage(100);
PlayerGUI.player.toggleTeletext();
```

How can I check beforehand if teletext is available in the stream?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API method to get this information via LibVLC as far as I know, so vlcj can't provide it either.

The best you can do is to try and set a page and immediately get the current page and see if it has returned a valid value.